# nested for loops not completing their cycles

Tags: c++, loops, cin

When I run this segment of my program, the only loop to work is the last for loop involving the 'week' variable.

```
cout << "Enter Building: ";
    cin >> building;
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "Enter Room: ";
    cin >> room;
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "Enter Numeric Month: ";
    cin >> monthIndex;
    monthIndex = monthIndex - 1;
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "Enter Week: ";
    cin >> week;
    cout << "\n";

    for (;building <= 30; building++)
    {
        for (;room <= 24; room++)
        {
            for (;monthIndex <= 11; monthIndex++)
            {
                for (;week <= 4; week++)
                {
                    cout << "Building: " << building << "\n";
                    cout << "Room: " << room << "\n";
                    cout << "Month: " << month[monthIndex] << "\n";
                    cout << "Week: " << week << "\n\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Example output:

Press 1 to print all of the ticket books

Press 2 to print a specific ticket book

Press 3 to exit the program

2 *menu selection*

Enter Building: 26

Enter Room: 20

Enter Numeric Month: 8

Enter Week: 2

Building: 26
Room: 20
Month: August
Week: 2

Building: 26
Room: 20
Month: August
Week: 3

Building: 26
Room: 20
Month: August
Week: 4

Comment: Are the variables of type `int`?

Comment: yes. and month[] is an array of month strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `week` to `1` at the end of last inner most `for` loop.

Comment: each variable is dependent upon the user input

Comment: once the week becomes 5 then for the next month it will never enter the for loop again as the value of week is already `5`.

Comment: How should I reset week to 1?

Comment: @BrandonWiser: At the end of innermost `for` loop `week = 1;` should do. But the problem doesn't stop there you may need to do something similar to `monthIndex` and `room` depending on your requirements.

Comment: I placed 'week = 1' after the innermost 'for' loop within the 'monthIndex' loop and it runs great!